# Apache httpd.h file missing on MacOSX after Mavericks Upgrade (** Updated for Yosemite **)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, apache, passenger

I am trying to run the `passenger-install-apache2-module` command and I keep getting this error:

`ext/apache2/mod_passenger.c:25:10: fatal error: 'httpd.h' file not found`

Not sure what happened to it, my local dev environment was fine until I upgraded to Mavericks - I had to update XCode and uninstall/reinstall the passenger gem.

I tried creating `httpd.h` in the `/etc/apache2` directory and pasting [this](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/apache/apache-643/apache/src/include/httpd.h) in but that didn't work.

I've no idea how to replace this file

Comment: httpd.h is supposed to be in /usr/include/apache2. I'm not yet sure what's going on, maybe Apple's update process broke something. More investigation is required. Maybe you can contact Apple?

Comment: exactly the same situation, exactly the same problem.

Comment: And you can't just copy-paste a random httpd.h. The contents have to exactly match the Apache version that you're actually running.

Comment: Thanks @Hongli, was going to try placing the file there just to see if it worked but `/usr/include` doesn't even seem to exist on my machine nevermind `/usr/include/apache2`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was having the same error. You need to:

1. `Update/install xcode.`
2. run `xcode-select --install` from the command line to reinstall the command line tools.

It worked for me, hopefully for you too!

The update also commented out the line:

`Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

So once I uncommented that it all loaded as normal.

** UPDATE FOR YOSEMITE **

In your `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file you'll need to change:

`<Directory />
   AllowOverride none
   Require all denied
</Directory>`

To:

`<Directory />
   AllowOverride none
   Require all granted
</Directory>`

Comment: thanks @Sean, downloading Command Line Tools now but that was the first thing I checked in XCode after downloading the update after Mavericks was installed, will report back with results.

Comment: the Phusion Passenger installation worked, just added the lines to my Apache config but my localhost is still just saying `It works!` so just need to fix that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had that issue to it was because I was using a vhosts file that my httpd.conf commented out. I just needed to uncomment that.

Comment: thanks, I'm not using anything any vhosts, the rails app is just in a directory on my Desktop which I access via `localhost` and updates the live site via svn, can't remember what I did for this stage the first time I installed Rails

Comment: __update:__ it's fine if I go to `localhost:3000` but before it ran fine on `localhost`, apache is listening on port 80 (checked httpd.conf) so not sure what's happening.... Just stopped apache and it made no difference, something weird is happening!

Comment: Anyone getting "can't install the software because it is not currently available from the software update server" - I have been getting this for the last couple of hours.

Comment: Which software? When you gem install passenger?

Comment: When running "xcode-select --install" and then following instructions.

Comment: Thanks @Sean, just noticed your Yosemite update and updated the title accordingly. My dev environment was not too bad to fix after this upgrade but for some reason I need to start passenger manually everytime I startup by running `sudo passenger start -p 80 --user=martin` in my app directory, I tried the above to fix it but nothing's changed - any ideas?

Comment: @martincarlin87 Did you reinstall the developer tools (xcode) when you updated to yosemite? It seems strange that you need to use sudo which makes me wonder if it is a permissions issue.

Comment: @Sean I reinstalled the apache module and noticed I hadn't so I have them installed now. I managed to fix it yesterday (I wasn't using any `VirtualHost` configs before, just a `DocumentRoot` but I have it now, then had a problem with the `.htaccess` file, finally fixed that and Passenger was starting with apache when it was restarted but after starting up today I'm getting an error when running `apachectl configtest` and `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES|grep -i passenger` when there were none yesterday after I got it working....

Answer (score 2):

During the mavericks upgrade several configuration files were saved as  ***previous*** and replaced by the install including:

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf~previous
/etc/group~previous
/etc/php.ini.default-5.2-previous
/etc/sshd_config~previous
/etc/syslog.conf~previous
```

Answer (score 0):

Another, related issue, is to do with /usr/share/httpd/build/config_vars.mk  you can see that cc is set incorrectly, and CC should read CC = /usr/bin/cc, likewise CPP should read CC = /usr/bin/cc -E